# I keep getting:[rospack] Error: stack/package tum_ardrone not found

Tags: ros, stack, package, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new to ROS and ubuntu but whatever i try i am keep getting the error so i hope someone can help me out!
I need to install 2 packages:

1. ardrone_autonomy
2. tum_ardrone

i followed these steps for both packages:

**# cd into ros root dir**
roscd

**# clone repository**
git clone git://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.git tum_ardrone

**# add to ros path (if required)**
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/tum_ardrone

**# build package (may take up to 10 minutes)**
rosmake tum_ardrone

even though they are both in opt/ros/hydro i can only run ardrone_autonomy
whenever i try to run tum_ardrone i am getting the error.

leroy@leroy-pc:~$ env |grep ROS

**ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros**

**ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks**

**ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311**

**ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=**

**ROS_DISTRO=hydro**

**ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros**

In my .bashrc file the source is: source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

i am using ROS hydro and ubuntu 12.04.

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193287/i-keep-getting:%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-tum_ardrone-not-found/) by [leroyv13](https://answers.ros.org/users/20275/leroyv13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to extend your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH when you want to use it.
You mentioned that you added the `tum_ardrone` folder to it (add to ros path).

But later your environment does not contain that anymore.
You have to prepend / append that folder everytime you want to use `rosbuild` packages from that location.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I supposed you have tum_ardrone in a workspace.Have you tried to do source .devel/setup.bash in your workspace?

If you do that and it doesn´t work it´s a installation problem.

---

Originally posted by [MarcosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20743/marcosm/) with karma: 11 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1